# Get view from Widget reference

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

In Eclipse, can I get the View ID given a reference to one of its widgets? I don't want to enumerate all views and traverse their hierarchies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [SWTbot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) and some manual bookkeeping for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use Control.getParent() API to go *up* the widget hierarchy starting with your widget. At some point, you will find the view part. Then you can get the info you need. I'd do this in the debugger first to make it easier to identify the class that the view part will have in the controls tree. It should be pretty obvious when you see it.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, ViewPart is not a member of the widget hierarchy...

Comment: @Neil, this is exactly my problem: How can I get the ViewPart?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Eclipse UI classes, but seems to me you're likely to run into a [PageBook][1] somewhere walking up the ancestors, maybe this helps?


  [1]: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/PageBook.html